# What does a return statement within a loop do?

Tags: c

In the code below, `str_replace_all` replaces all occurrences of `oldc` with `newc`. `str_replace_first` is only supposed to replace the first occurrence of `oldc` with `newc`.

So `str_replace_all` loops through and it replaces all occurrences of `oldc` with `newc`, easy enough to understand. In the second function `str_replace_first` the code is identical, except for `return 1` after finding and replacing the char. I don't exactly understand what `return 1` does in this case. From what I am understanding it "breaks" the loop? I was hoping somebody could give me an explanation on how it replaces only the first occurrence.

```
size_t str_replace_all(char s[], int oldc, int newc)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t count = 0;

    for (i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)oldc)
        {
            s[i] = (char)newc;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count; 
}


int str_replace_first(char s[], int oldc, int newc)
{

    size_t i;

    for (i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)oldc)
        {
            s[i] = (char)newc; 
            return 1; /* What exactly does this do? */
        }
    }
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use a debugger** (`gdb`) to run *step by step* your program (and query some program state, e.g. variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return 1` escapes the function and returns a 1 to whatever has called it. `return` effectively escapes any function when it is called, this can be used in many applications to exit a function before it is 'complete'.

In this case:

```
int str_replace_first(char s[], int oldc, int newc)
{

    size_t i;

    for (i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == (char)oldc)
        {
            s[i] = (char)newc; 
            return 1; /* What exactly does this do? */
        }
    }
        return 0; 
}
```

The loop continues until it finds a character that matches oldc then replaces it with newc, then exits immediately before continuing on again. So as soon as it finds a match it will replace it then exit.

Answer (score 0):

Here in `str_replace_first` when

```
s[i] == (char)oldc
```

condition becomes true in the loop, then then that character(old character) is replaced by the new one. and then `return 1` returns the control to the calling function with a  value of 1.(i.e neither the loop nor the function continues further).

1 was returned to mark that only 1 character was replaced.